# Gremlin-Traversing Find all vertex not related to a specific vertex

Tags: gremlin, orientdb, graph-traversal

This is the scenario: I have a number of users vertex in a orient-db.
I want to retrieve all users that are NOT friend of a specific user where friend are an edge.
I need the gremlin command to that. 
Any one could help me? 
Thank you.
Diego

Answer (score 2):

Because you want to find ALL users that are NOT friends with a specific user, I'm not sure there is a very efficient way to do this one.  I'm using the toy graph to demonstrate, but I'm assuming that all the vertices are user and all the edges are friend edges.  I'd do something like:

```
gremlin> g = TinkerGraphFactory.createTinkerGraph()
==>tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6]
gremlin> l=[g.v(1)] as Set;g.v(1).out.fill(l)                 
==>v[1]
==>v[2]
==>v[4]
==>v[3]
```

so get the specific user into the list `l` as well as their friends

```
gremlin> g.V.except(l)                                        
==>v[6]
==>v[5]
```

then find everyone else except those people.  that would be everyone who wasn't a friend of the specific user or that specific user himself.  I don't particularly like that you have to iterate `g.V` as it involves a linear scan of all friends, but I can't think of any easier way to find everyone NOT in that initial set.